# Vue-apollo refetch query from another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I wonder if it's possible to refetch a query from one component so it would be updated in another component without refreshing the component itself. After a mutation, I see that the apollo cache has been updated, but I don't see the data in my other component that is "alive" already.
My global apollo fetch policy is:

```
watchQuery: {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out, that I need to `update` my cache directly with `writeQuery`. Because `refetchQuery` gives you a new object, but if you want it to be snappy, you need to mutate your existing object in your apollo cache. A code example would be:

```
  .mutate({
    mutation: CREATE_USER,
    variables: { ...user },
    update(store, { data: { createUser } }) {
      const data = store.readQuery({ query: LIST_USERS })
      data.users.items.push(createUser)
      store.writeQuery({ query: LIST_USERS, data })
    }
  })
```